# I need clarification about a claim with reference to the dimension of a free module that is summand of a free module.

Tags: modules, free-modules

I am trying to understand the claim that dim$_k(P)= 4|I|$ in the following proof.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It boils down to the following statement:

> If $R$ is a $k$-vector space with a compatible multiplication that makes it a ring (altogether, a $k$-algebra), and if $M$ is a free
>   $R$-module of rank $r$, then $M$ is a $k$-vector space, and its dimension as such is
>   $$\dim_k(M)=r\dim_k(R)$$

which is more or less obvious from the definitions - you can set up a $k$-basis for $M$ into a rectangular fashion.

---

Edit: whenever an  $R$-module $M$ is free, it means that it has a basis - that is, a family of elements of the module, say $ \{e_i\}_{i\in I}$, such that any $x\in M$ is an $R$-linear combination of the $e_i$'s in a unique way.

If $\{f_j\}_{j=1}^d$ is a $k$ basis of $R$ (as a $k$-vector space), you can then easily prove that $\{f_je_i\}$ is a $k$-basis of $M$, with $d|I|$ elements.

Comment: Can you show how to prove this, I am sort of new to modules and really just doing some comparisons to short exact sequences of groups led me here.

Comment: Did you mean commutative ring? The link points to wiki article about invariant basis number. In the situation above $R=M_2(F)$ is not commutative.

Comment: And does this not also assume that the basis is finite, where in the proof above they use a arbitrary index set $I$ when talking about a basis for $P$.

Comment: @tmpys My bad, I overlooked the commutative part. About the index, it doesn't matter if it's infinite, the result still holds ($rd$ is infinite in this case, and can't be equal to $2$ as in the picture you posted)

Comment: So do we need the commutative part?

Comment: @tmpys No we don't, all you need is the existence of a basis. I'll edit the post.

Comment: one last thing, when you say k-basis, you mean as a k-module and not a R-module right?

Comment: @tmpys Yes, but since $k$ is a field instead of $k$-module one usually says $k$-vector space (but the definition is the same as for modules)